# React.js updating state on onclick function causing infinite loop while rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering this code inside a loop using array.map function like this

```
this.props.groups.map((group, i) => {
 return (
    <li key={i} onClick={this.selectGroup.bind(this, i)}
     <span className="name">{group.name}</span>
    </li>
 );
});
```

and inside `selectGroup` function, I am updating state. But I am getting infinite loop in the console while logging state value.

```
selectGroup(val){
 this.setState({id: val});
}
```

Any help?

Comment: can you show, `loop` and `selectGroup` method ? and where you are using `console.log` ?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Show your loop and map.

Comment: Why `react-redux`? It seems there is nothing related to `react-redux` in your question.

Comment: @Mayank Shukla. I updated my question

Comment: @G0dsquad It would lead to a infinite loop because onClick expects a function and your way it will get a value

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri `this.selectGroup.bind(this, i)` is a function.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri is right, he is saying if he use `this.selectGroup(i)` then it will a infinite loop, like @G0dsquad is suggesting.

Comment: @MayankShukla You understood it right

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri my mistake, but you can also do `() => this.selectGroup(i)` surely?

Comment: Try `onClick={() => this.selectGroup(i)}` instead `onClick={this.selectGroup.bind(this, i)}`. And bind your function in constructor.

Comment: @G0dsquad  `() => this. selectGroup(i)` and `this.selectGroup.bind(this, i)` are one and the same thing

Comment: @h_a86 all the code that u showed is proper, there is no issue in that, probelm is somewhere else, one more thing how r u so sure that its a infinite loop ??

Comment: People here need to read what `bind` is, especially @Shubham Khatri. Posted code alone can't cause infinite loop. The question is not answerable in this form.

Comment: can you try ```onClick ={() => this. selectGroup(i)}``` and bind the main function in your constructor.

Comment: Above code does not cause an infinite loop. There's something missing.

Comment: @Nitish Phanse same results

Comment: I am getting this error https://www.screencast.com/t/BF7TLSWmj if I remove updatestate code, everything works fine

Comment: @h_a86 Haha, of course same result. Because this is the same thing. You get infinite loop for different reason. Create demo, or don't expect people to guess what code you are not showing causes the issue.

Comment: in the code, I am having nothing other than these 2 snippets

Comment: @G0dsquad, yup, after commenting state update, everything works fine.

Comment: @h_a86 saw that my comment was already answered earlier on, so removed. It has to be something to do with the state method being called over and over as you know. Are you sure there's no other code? No-one else here can reproduce this.

Comment: I resolved the problem myself by adding a condition on val

Comment: Can you make a jsbin link with the entire code.. will be easy to understand